# How to enable secure context in react-native-webview?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview

I use the react native webview component to load up my log in screen on the Mobile application. With the latest Safari on iOS update in iOS 15, there is a need to make the webview load in a secure context. I use `https://<hostname>` to load the webview.

But when I try to use `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey` function, the method throws an exception saying `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.subtle()[f]')`

Is there some way I can load the webview in a secure context other than just having a https session?

Link from Apple team: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/279628/webkit

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: we are looking for the same answer. any luck yet?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by importing react-native-webview-crypto into my monorepo and patching it locally like this:

```
+++ b/packages/react-native-webview-crypto/index.js
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 const React = require("react");
 const { StyleSheet, View, Platform } = require("react-native");
 const { WebView } = require("react-native-webview");
+const { MainBundlePath } = require("react-native-fs")
 const { MainWorker, webViewWorkerString } = require("webview-crypto");
 
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
@@ -137,7 +138,7 @@ class PolyfillCrypto extends React.Component {
     const code = `((function () {${webViewWorkerString};${internalLibrary}})())`;
     const source = Platform.select({
       android: { source: { uri } },
-      ios: undefined,
+      ios: { source: { uri: `file://${MainBundlePath}/blank.html` }},
     });
```

Additionally I've added `blank.html` file with content:

```
<html />
```

to my Resources in Xcode.

So basically after this change it's doing same thing for Ios as it used to do for Android.